# How to export CSV without commas in unpopulated cells?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, regex, csv

I have a form converter which simply rearranges columns. I use a script to paste Values only into another sheet for export and uploading onto another website.

However, when I go to export, it seems to save a bunch of commas after the populated cells. As far as I can tell, these cells are and must be empty.

When I open in Excel, and manually clear contents of the empty cells, the commas disappear.

My question is how do I export without saving these commas, just whats in the populated cells?

[image: Export form. Cells below should be completely empty]

[image: Windows preview, showing commas. should not be there]

Here's my export script:

```
function CopyPasteValues() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('O3:AS90').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Export'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Converter!O3:AS90').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('F27').activate();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The answers pretty embarrassing. I had an if statement populating " " a bunch of rows instead of "" - i.e where nothing was required. Adding a space will add a comma in CSV. I did not know.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is kind of the standard behaviour when exporting Comma Separated Values from Google Sheets. If you wish to "correct" it, you can run a regex on it and then apply a copy on the values:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(A:A, ",,,,,,|,,,,,|,,,,|,,,|,,", ","))
```

[image: 0]